# Highchart tooltip value should be format based on locale

Tags: java, highcharts

For example, I want to display the below format:

`Italy Format : 1.325.000`
`Us Format : 1,325,000`
etc.

But `highchart` display another format using the below response.
Based on locale it shows the value in tooltip dynamically.
I am trying with below response.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    "tooltip" : {
      "shared" : true
    },
    "legend" : {
      "enabled" : true,
      "reversed" : false
    },
    "credits" : {
      "enabled" : false
    },
    "exporting" : {
      "enabled" : false
    },
    "chart" : {
      "zoomType" : "xy"
    },
    "title" : {
      "text" : "Financial analytic"
    },
    "xAxis" : [ {
      "categories" : [ "Amar", "Kiran", "Venkatesh" ],
      "crosshair" : true
    } ],
    "yAxis" : [ {
      "title" : {
        "text" : "Financial"
      },
      "labels" : {
        "format" : "${value:.2f}USD"
      }
    } ],
    "series" : [ {
      "type" : "column",
      "name" : "Financial",
      "data" : [ 1325000.0, 1740000.0, 1560000.0 ],
      "tooltip" : {
        "valueDecimals" : 2,
        "valuePrefix" : "$",
        "valueSuffix" : "USD"
      },
      "yAxis" : 0
    }]

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `thousandsSep` in the `lang` options:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        thousandsSep: ','
    }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4m79t50g/1/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/lang.thousandsSep

Comment: You are given static format for any locale.Some locales having dots(.),some are having commas(,), and some are having both combination (, and .). My requirement is based on locale it should be format in highchart tooltip.

Comment: Hi @Kiran, So you need to check the location of user in some way and depend on that set `thousandsSep` property.